# Cambiar ubicación física de base de datos SQlite en Entity Framework 6

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework

Si bien he leído algunos tutoriales en general son para MySQL o SQL, no logro darme cuenta como cambiar la ubicación física de la base de datos para que por ejemplo quede en la carpeta de documentos del usuario y no en la carpeta Appdata de difícil acceso para el usuario

La idea es que si el usuario tiene sincronizada la carpeta de Documentos con Dropbox, Google Drive, etc... automáticamente se respalde la base de datos.

Se que hay que cambiar o crear otro constructor pero no he dado con la solución

```
public FSBaseDatosEntities()
        : base("name=FSBaseDatosEntities")
    {
    }
```

Comment: `name=FSBaseDatosEntities` es el nombre de la conexion en el web.config cierto?

Comment: @Einer sí y es el nombre que figura en el constructor también